# How to fix "LoadError: DimensionMismatch ("cannot broadcast array to have fewer dimensions")"

Tags: indexing, julia, ode, differentialequations.jl

I'd like to solve the following two coupled differential equations numerically:

```
d/dt Phi_i = 1 - 1/N * \sum_{j=1}^N( k_{ij} sin(Phi_i - Phi_j + a) 
d/dt k_{ij} = - epsilon * (sin(Phi_i - Phi_j + b) + k_{ij}
```

with defined starting conditions phi_0 (1-dim array with N entries) and k_0 (2-dim array with NxN entries)

I tried this: Using DifferentialEquations.js, build a matrix of initial starting conditions u0 = hcat(Phi_0, k_0) (2-dim array, Nx(N+1)), and somehow define that the first equation applies to to first column (in my code [:,1]) , and the second equation applies to the other columns (in my code [:,2:N+1]).

```
using Distributions
using DifferentialEquations

N = 100
phi0 = rand(N)*2*pi
k0 = rand(Uniform(-1,1), N,N)

function dynamics(du, u, p, t)
    a = 0.3*pi 
    b = -0.53*pi 
    epsi = 0.01 

    du[:,1] .= 1 .- 1/N .* sum.([u[i,j+1] * sin(u[i,1] - u[j,1] + a) for i in 1:N, j in 1:N], dims=2)
    du[:,2:N+1] .= .- epsi .* [sin(u[i,1] - u[j,1] + b) + u[i,j+1] for i in 1:N, j in 1:N]
end

u0 = hcat(phi0, k0)
tspan = (0.0, 200.0)
prob = ODEProblem(dynamics, u0, tspan)
sol = solve(prob)
```

Running this lines of code result in this error:

```
LoadError: DimensionMismatch ("cannot broadcast array to have fewer dimensions")in expression starting at line 47 (which is sol = solve(prob))
```

I'm new to Julia, and I'm not sure if im heading in the right direction with this. Please help me!

Comment: The broadcast (dot) in `sum.([u[i,j+1] * sin(u[i,1] - u[j,1] + a) for i in 1:N, j in 1:N], dims=2)` seems suspicious. It will try to call `sum(::Float64, dims=2)` which should error as well.

Comment: changed it, but the error message stayed the same.

Comment: Try to two extra lines: `temp = 1 .- 1/N .* sum([u[i,j+1] * sin(u[i,1] - u[j,1] + a) for i in 1:N, j in 1:N], dims=2)` and `println("size of arrays: ", size(du), " and ",  size(temp))` before the assignment to `du` and see what it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, edit the first package, which is `Distributions` and not `Distribution`, it took me a while to find the error xD

The main problem is the `.=` in your first equation. When you do that, you don't just assign new values to an array, you're making a `view`. I cannot explain you exactly what is a view, but what I can tell you is that, when you this kind of assign, the left and right side must have the same type.

For example:

```
N = 100
u = rand(N,N+1)
du = rand(N,N+1)

julia> u[:,1] .= du[:,1]
100-element view(::Array{Float64,2}, :, 1) with eltype Float64:
 0.2948248997313967 
 0.2152933893895821 
 0.09114453738716022
 0.35018616658607926
 0.7788869975259098 
 0.2833659299216609 
 0.9093344091412392 
...
```

The result is a `view` and not a Vector. With this syntax, left and right sides must have same type, and that does not happen in your example. Note that the types of `rand(5)` and `rand(5,1)` are different in Julia: the first is an `Array{Float64,1}` and the other is `Array{Float64,2}`. In your code, `d[:,1]` is an `Array{Float64,1}` but `1 .- 1/N .* sum.([u[i,j+1] * sin(u[i,1] - u[j,1] + a) for i in 1:N, j in 1:N], dims=2)` is an `Array{Float64,2}`, that's why it doesn't work. You have two choices, change the equal sign for:

```
du[:,1] = ...
```

Or:

```
du[:,1] .= 1 .- 1/N .* sum.([u[i,j+1] * sin(u[i,1] - u[j,1] + a) for i in 1:N, j in 1:N], dims=2)[:,1]
```

The first choice is just a basic assign, the second choice uses the `view` way and matches the types of both sides.

Comment: It seems you are right, but I don't think it's a problem with `view`. The problem is that `broadcast` itself doesn't like assignment of a 2D source to a 1D destination. If you want broadcasted assignment, it is necessary to make sure that the output of `sum` is squeezed to 1D.

Comment: In that case `dropdims` is more efficient than `[:,1]`, but the simplest solution is to just drop the dot in the assignment.

Comment: didn't know about `dropdims` function, thanks. And after posting I remembered that you could just `vec()` it, probably more efficient as well. drop the dot is the simplest yeah, just put the second example in case OP wanted to mantain aesthetics of code. I would remove the dots of both equations, though.